# CSS : Issue with parent class

Tags: css

I have a question about parent classes with CSS.

I need to modify on my homepage some components like `panel-body`, `panel-footer` etc .. only on my homepage.

So I would like to define a parent class like this :

```
<div class="row parent-class">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 visu-pharma">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="../img/Visuel-Pharmacopée.jpg" alt="VisuPharma"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body ">
                <p class="p-text">NOW AVAILABLE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a parent class named `.parent-class` in the first line.

In my CSS file, I would like to set something like this :

```
.parent-class {
    .panel-body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. This example is simple because you could say me to make that :

```
.parent-class.panel-body{}
```

But I have maybe 20 different classes depending from `parent-class` and I would like to make generic CSS.

Something is false in my CSS conception ?

Comment: What you are trying to do looks like SCSS, it helps you to reduce code when writing CSS. But if you are not using something like LESS or SASS, you need to formulate that individually for each CSS rule (which is what the preprocessors translate to anyways).

Comment: Just a minor comment: `.parent-class.panel-body{}` will not work, there's a space missing, it ought to be `.parent-class .panel-body{}`.

Comment: So if I want to keep CSS in my project because I am not using LESS or SASS, I can't reduce my code and remove redondant parent-class ? I have to define this parent-class for each child-class ?

Comment: @Paul Sorry I forgot the space between classes ;)

Comment: Exactly, if you are not using a preprocessor, you have to go the extra mile and write it yourself.

Comment: @Paul Ok it's too bad to my mind :/ Thank you with your answer anyway !

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't support nested selectors. What you are trying to do is a pure SCSS or Less feature. But for styles that are the same in every child class you could do something like:

```css
.parent-class [class^="panel-"] {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Not sure if this helps though, because for every style that's different you still need your parent class. Or you could just use scss :)